# Solr search arabic site, plural and singular words

Tags: search, solr, arabic

I am using solr to implement search for an Arabic site, and i want normalize plural words into singular words and visa versa, so searching for "كتاب"  gets me any document that contains "كتاب" or "كتب" is this possible in solr, highly appreciate your input

Comment: Probably helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681281/need-explanation-on-language-stemmer-of-solr

Comment: There is [a package in Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicNormalizationFilter.html) (and therefore available in Solr) that is dedicated to the Arabic language. Unfortunately I know not enough about Arabic to tell you, if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, i used it but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

There was a presentation at the Lucene/Solr Revolution by Ramzi Alqrainy about Solr's support for Arabic and common issues. It is now [available online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6zehH_FOSk).

Comment: Thanks, i did what was presented but did not satisfy my requiment

Answer (score 1):

You need a stemmer to bring words into their origins in both indexing/search, try [Khoja's stemmer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/arabicstemmer/) or [Assem's stemmer](http://www.arabicstemmer.com/)

Solr by default is using [a light stemmer for Arabic](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Arabic) but seems you needs a deep stemmer that brings roots of the word.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i already tried to create my own custom Arabic stem filter, but do not know what the correct implementation of the  incrementToken() method would be, highly appreciate your input..